# Raise TypeError in class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, exception

I have the following simple code:

```
class testing:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_1 = testing("a", "b", "c")
```

When i execute it everything works well but when i increase `arg_1` with `"d"` like that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_1 = testing("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Now i want to raise an exception:

```
class testing:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        try:
            self.arg1 = arg1
            self.arg2 = arg2
            self.arg3 = arg3
        except TypeError:
            print("Error, to many values")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_1 = testing("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

I get the same error message. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is implicitly passed during the call for initialization. The `try-except` won't even get executed, the error occurs when *the call* is made. You've specified three additional args, not four.

If you *need* to check for that you should wrap the *call* made when you initialize in a `try-except`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arg_1 = testing("a", "b", "c", "d")
    except TypeError:
        print("Error, to many values")
```

for whatever purpose you need.

Answer (score 1):

Python is throwing an error when trying to call **init**(), so your custom error is never reached. If you want to use a custom error in this case, you need to support variable argument lengths with *args.

```
class testing:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 3:
            print("Error, too many values")
            return
        self.arg1 = args[0]
        self.arg2 = args[1]
        self.arg3 = args[2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_1 = testing("a", "b", "c")
```